# Auto redirect on Home/Error when start debug

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a very strange issue.
Suddenly, when I start debugging on my project, I am redirected to `Home/Error` instead of `Home/Index`
without any apparent error or message.

The application is very simple because I just created it today.

This is my startup:

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.SystemDefault;
    Configuration = configuration;
}

public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);

    services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal);
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.EnableForHttps = true;
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });

    // Without AddNewtonsoftJson actions that receive JSON Objects Body will return error 406
    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();

    services.AddSingleton<ITempDataProvider, CookieTempDataProvider>();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    });
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

    services.AddTransient<IElasticsearchService, ElasticsearchService>();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public static void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    // Enable compression (must be before UseStaticFiles)
    app.UseResponseCompression();

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();

    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
}
```

And this is (the only one for now) my controller:

```cs
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, IElasticsearchService elasticsearchService)
    : base (logger, httpContextAccessor, elasticsearchService) { }

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Dictionary<string, string> @params)
{
    // some code

    return View();
}

public IActionResult Privacy()
{
    return View();
}

[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public IActionResult Error()
{
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;
    if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
    {
        errorMessage = TempData["ErrorMessage"].ToString();
        TempData["ErrorMessage"] = null;
    }
    ViewBag.ErrorMessage = errorMessage;

    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
}
```

Comment: Upon opening the url, do you see any errors in the console in your browser?

Comment: No there aren't erorrs.

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`


Choose the second one. And remove the first one. Possibly, you will fix your problem

Comment: May be other sequence of service lines will work for you, Sequence is compulsory

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem on my own, maybe the issue was, that I used a `RedirectToPermanent()` on my `Index` and from then on, it always redirect me on `Error`.

I cleaned the `cache` and the `temporary files` and now it seems to work.